# Is it possible to use camel 2.13.4 with camel-saxon 3.14.0?

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, saxon, spring-camel

I am trying to update the version of camel-saxon being used in my project from 2.13.4 to 3.14.0 while keeping the version of camel-core at 2.13.4. Also I am building with Java 1.8.265. Once I change the version of camel-saxon from 2.13.4 to 3.14.0 in my pom.xml and try building with maven clean install I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.language.xquery.XQueryLanguage.property(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.camel.language.xquery.XQueryLanguage.configureBuilder(XQueryLanguage.java:85)
    at org.apache.camel.language.xquery.XQueryLanguage.createExpression(XQueryLanguage.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.language.xquery.XQueryLanguage.createExpression(XQueryLanguage.java:67)
```

My first thought was to try to upgrade camel-core from 2.13.4 to 3.14.0 but I would like to avoid that if possible for the time being. So is there an api/jar or something else I can use to bridge the gap between camel-core and camel-saxon or is the only way to upgrade camel-saxon by updating both dependencies?

If anyone is interested what error I get when trying to upgrade camel-core to 3.14.0 along with camel-saxon. I get the following error:

> org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
> route2 at: >>> InOut[inOut] <<< in route:
> Route(route2)[From[vm:urn:myurn] -> [ConvertBodyTo... because of
> Failed to resolve endpoint:
> xslt://path/to/file/myfile.xsl?transformerFactory=tFactory
> due to: Error binding property (transformerFactory=tFactory) with
> name: transformerFactory on bean:
> xslt://path/to/file/myfile.xsl?transformerFactory=tFactory
> with value: tFactory

and route:

```
<bean id="tFactory" class="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
<camelContext trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
        <from uri="vm:urn:myurn" />
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
        <log message="my message" loggingLevel="INFO"
            logName="my.logname" />
        <inOut uri="xslt:path/to/file/myfile.xsl?transformerFactory=tFactory"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
        <log message="my message" loggingLevel="INFO"
                logName="my.log" />
        <inOut uri="mock:processedout"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Camel, but my guess would be (a) it's unlikely to work and (b) the fact that you got a `NoSuchMethodError` strongly suggests that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your camel dependencies should always match with the version of camel you're using. Sometimes you might want/need to change version of transitive dependency if one of your camel dependencies is using version of a library that has a bug that's been patched in later (minor) version but that's about it.

A lot has changed between Camel version 2.13.4 and 3.14.x including the fact that Camel 2.25.0 reached it's EOL (end of life) in [January 2022](https://camel.apache.org/blog/2020/03/LTS-Release-Schedule/) meaning that it will no longer receive updates.

Your options are either to upgrade your integration to more recent camel version or implement a custom processor or camel-component that does what you do with camel-saxon in your integration but by using more recent versions of saxon related libraries.